# What coming changes might render current IFR equipment worthless in the foreseeable future?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, avionics

I'm shopping for my first aircraft.  I have found a very well cared for 172 that is VFR.  I also found an IFR-certified 172 that is higher time and cosmetically is showing its age.  I inquired about the expense of updating the VFR plane to IFR and the seller mentioned that due to some upcoming changes in IFR requirements even a plane that is IFR rated today may require a substantial investment to keep it IFR.

I've done a lot of searching and can't find anything to substantiate that statement.  The closest thing I found was an article from the AOPA way back in 1997 where the FAA had proposed rule changes that would have made a lot of (then) IFR compliant GPS units non-compliant.

What, if any, regulatory changes are on the horizon that might render the IFR certified equipment I buy today worthless tomorrow in the context of IFR?

Comment: He may be referring to the ["ADS-B Out"](http://www.aopa.org/Advocacy/Air-Traffic-Services-,-a-,-Technology/Air-Traffic-Services-Brief-Automatic-Dependent-Surveillance-Broadcast-ADS-B) requirement, which is becoming mandatory in 2020 (unless delayed).  However, that is not an IFR requirement, its an "every-plane" requirement.

Comment: I've added a faa-regulations tag because I assume you only fly in FAA airspace. Please adjust if necessary.

Comment: Also of interest: [FAA NextGen](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/programs/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the moment the answer is "None" - with two exceptions:

1. **LORAN receivers**
   These are already worthless because the US has shut down our LORAN chains.
   They are jokingly referred to as "IFR-Certified Lead Bricks".
2. **ADFs**
   The FAA is killing off NDBs one by one - an ADF is basically an expensive, drag-producing AM Radio in many parts of the country, and its utility is in steady decline.

Other than that the core IFR technologies are pretty much sticking around:

- **VOR/LOC/ILS** isn't going anywhere.
  Some VORs are getting decommissioned, but even the bleakest plans call for the FAA to maintain a "minimal operational network" of VORs as a backup in the event of trouble with the GPS satellites..
- **DME** is sticking around.
  Lots of planes flying around use DME still, and there are lots of DME approaches which serve as good backups for GPS approaches.
- **(WAAS) GPS** is the current "best technology" & isn't going away soon.
  The FAA ***LOVES*** WAAS GPS. It lets them get ILS-type approaches to pretty much any runway without expensive ground equipment to install/maintain/test. If you have an IFR-Certified WAAS GPS in your aircraft you're on the cutting edge of IFR navigation equipment, even if the GPS itself is older-generation technology (such as the popular Garmin 430W).
  If your GPS is not [WAAS capable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Area_Augmentation_System) it's still going to be usable, but it's much more limited. It may also pose some problems for you down the road (see below).

---

Some equipment regulations are changing (as part of the [ADS-B Out mandate](http://www.aopa.org/Advocacy/Air-Traffic-Services-,-a-,-Technology/Air-Traffic-Services-Brief-Automatic-Dependent-Surveillance-Broadcast-ADS-B) coming in 2020), but that's not an IFR-specific thing.

The crux of the ADS-B Out mandate is if you want to fly in airspace where a Mode C transponder is currently required you will need two things in your aircraft (if they're not already installed):

- An ADS-B Out transmitter to broadcast your position.
  This can be achieved in two ways:
  A Mode S transponder with Extended Squitter (1090ES); or
  A 987MHz Universal Access Transceiver (UAT)
- A suitably accurate position source to talk to the transmitter.
  Currently that means a WAAS GPS - either a panel-mounted device or a separate "blind" box.

The cost of complying with this mandate falls somewhere within a wide range: If you want a modern WAAS GPS with a touchscreen interface that will let you fly GPS approaches and a new transponder to do the broadcasting part you're going to spend a lot more money than if you install a Universal Access Transceiver and blind GPS source that do the absolute minimum required to comply.